# Bash Scripts in the Windows 10 Ubuntu Shell

Tags: windows, bash

I'm attempting to write a relatively straightforward bit of bash code. I'm working in the Ubuntu Shell on Windows 10. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
COUNTER=1
while [$COUNTER -le 10] ; do
    echo $COUNTER
    let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```

Pretty straightforward, but no matter how I tweak the format (ie do on the next line instead, no tabs, etc.), I get the following two errors:

```
./cfish.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./cfish.sh: line 6: `done'
```

As a disclaimer, I don't have a ton of experience with bash scripts. However, I'm pretty sure that something this simple is correct, and am therefor wondering if the errors I'm getting are a byproduct of working in the Ubuntu Shell within Windows 10.

Has anyone had a similar problem OR can anyone spot some incredibly stupid mistake I'm making with my bash script?

Comment: Is that exactly your script? If so, add spaces before and after the brackets in the conditional test: [ $COUNTER -le 10 ]

Answer (score 0):

bash is a very whitespace-sensitive language. `[` is not just syntax, it is the name of a command. At a bash prompt, enter `help [` to read more. The shell uses whitespace to separate commands from arguments.

Use this:

```
while [ $COUNTER -le 10 ] ; do
```

Also, make sure that the file is not saved with DOS-style line endings. The syntax error might be that your scripts says `done\r` with a trailing carriage return. Check it with `file cfish.sh` and verify you don't get the answer "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators". If you do, fix it with `dos2unix cfish.sh`, and configure your editor accordingly.